# How are units converted to metric in translations of D&D 3.5?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, translations

I have heard that some foreign language translations of 3.5 use meters in the rules text instead of feet.  How big is a square in these metric translations? Are weight measurements given in Newtons or kilograms?

Comment: See http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5545/concerns-over-the-dd-translations-question for a meta question relating to this question

Comment: It seems strange to me that they would use the metric system, but spell *metre* wrong.

Comment: @IanMacDonald *Meter* and *metre* are both correct, depending on where you live. Compare *theater* and *theatre*.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie The places where *meter* is the correct spelling is not also a place where I would expect them to use the metric system. This is why it seems strange to me. Why go half-way with the conversion?

Comment: Note to potential answerers: I've edited this to *not* be a request for a list, even a short list. We don't want a bunch of answers just saying "oh, this one uses metric too." With a small change, I've made the question instead about how metric works/is used in translation-editions that use metric.

Comment: @IanMacDonald Because SI unit use and regional English spelling are entirely unrelated. *Meter* is standard in Canada and the US (though this Canadian personally prefers *metre*). Contrary to appearances, metric is in wide use in North America, particularly in the scientific community.

Comment: Though perhaps not as widely as might be wished, see eg [the famous "lithobraking" end to the Mars Climate Orbiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Climate_Orbiter#Cause_of_failure) (yes, I know atmposheric disintegration is hardly "lithobraking", but the astrophysicist friend who told me the news used that neologism, and I find it's too good a word not to get it out there!).

Comment: They should have kept the US standard measures. It definitely adds to the medieval look and feel of the game. ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Dungeons & Dragons books translated into Portuguese use the metric system.
The translator represented 1 yard as 1 meter, 5 feet as 1.5m and 1 pound as 0.5 kg.

As an example, a dagger in the 3.5 Player's Handbook (Livro do Jogador) weighs 0.5kg and its range is 3m.

Comment: This is true for both Brazillian Portuguese and Portugal's Portuguese.

Answer (score 7):

The German translation also uses meters, 5 feet being 1.5m.

A fireball for example has a range of 120m plus 12m per Level and a radius of 6m.

Weight is measured in "Pfund" which is the same as pounds.

Jump distances and DCs are measured in meters, too. For example, jumping over a chasm starts at 1.5m at DC 5 and goes up by 5 for each 1.5m. Jumping over an obstacle starts at DC 4 for 30cm and goes up by 4 for each 30cm.

Comment: Out of curiosity: how are Jump DCs calculated?

Comment: @burlap added jump distances.

Comment: @nvoigt Thanks! Jumping doesn't seem any easier with metric DCs than converting feet to meters in my head each time...

Answer (score 6):

The Italian edition of D&D 3.5 books have 5 feet being 1.5 meters.

I'm not totally sure about pounds, but I have my 3.0 manuals in Italian and 1 pound is 0.45 kg